# A change in the kinetic energy of a charged particle in a magnetic field in the instant co-moving frame?

Tags: electromagnetism, classical-electrodynamics

Suppose a charge is moving at a non-relativistic velocity in a magnetic field $B$.

Switching to the instantaneous comoving frame of the charge where its initial velocity is zero, the electromagnetic field is also $B$ since the charge is travelling non-relativistically. Yet in this fixed comoving frame, the kinetic energy of the particle changes with time, despite the magnetic field not doing work on the charge: **How is this possible?**